# Keep data between two event calls

Tags: php, symfony, events

I have a class which methods are subscribed for two events

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class WatermarkListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $data;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSetData',
        );
    }

    public function postUpload(Event $event)
    {
        dump($event);
        dump($this->data);
        exit;
    }

    public function onPresetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $this->data = $event->getData();
        dump($this->data);
    }
}
```

`FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` is fired first and populates `$this->data` The problem is that when the second event `postUpload` is fired the value of `$this->data` is null. How can I keep the data in `$this->data` between those two event calls?

Comment: Are you calling both events from URL?

Comment: Where postUpload is subscribed?

Comment: Are your events fired in the same request?

Comment: @JakubZalas yes

MaxP:. postUpload is subscribed to vichuploaderbundle vich_uploader.post_upload,



Umair: both events are fired on form submit

Comment: Are you sure that both events are handled by the same instance of your event listener? Can you show the code that register the listener for both events?

Comment: Good comment @xabbuh, is your subscriber defined as symfony 2 service ?